# Angular - horizontal Stepper (components inside step-content always get initialized )

Tags: angular

Parent component .ts file

```
 <mat-stepper #stepper labelPosition="bottom">
    <mat-step label="Search">
        <app-search-component></app-search-component>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step label="Detail">
        <app-detail-component></app-detail-component>
    </mat-step>
<mat-stepper>
```

I am using angular stepper and in 2 steps, using individual component (search and details).
After searching on search component, wanted to pass the search result on detail page. Which i am planning to achieve via

1. When i click on search data row (Search results displayed on table format) , i am saving this data into variable using simple services
2. On second component (Detail Component), ngOnInit i would like to retrieve this data.

But the problem is when i load the page both component get initialized together,

Is there a way i can only initialize first component at first and than second when i clicked on search result row?

Thank you

Is there a way i can only initialize first component at first and than second when i clicked on search result row?

Comment: You can lazy load content within a step: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#lazy-rendering

Comment: <mat-stepper #stepper labelPosition="bottom">
    <mat-step label="Search">
      <ng-template matStepContent>
      <app-search-component></app-search-component>
    </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Detail">
      <ng-template matStepContent>
      <app-detail-component></app-detail-component>
  </mat-step>
 <mat-stepper>

Comment: Thank you bizzybob. above code use lazy loading will resolve my issue

Comment: BizzyBob
but when i come back to first steps after first selection  i am not able to execute init() method again for second components. AM i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research for it, and looks like that component has an output property named selectionChange, that will emit an event every time you change the step.

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepper
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7259

That being said, if you do:

```
<mat-stepper #stepper labelPosition="bottom" (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)">
    <mat-step label="Search">
        <app-search-component></app-search-component>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step label="Detail">
        <app-detail-component></app-detail-component>
    </mat-step>
<mat-stepper>
```

You should be able to handle that event, and pass the necessary information to the detail component as an input property, that way you won't need the ngOnInit to run every single time.

I know it ruins the whole using service to pass data between siblings idea, this is a more React based approach (moving the state upwards), but it can work.

Comment: I am able to pass the necessary information from search  to details via service variables but can not retrieve it on detail component. ( I was planned to retrieve on ngOnInit() but can not do that as all component load at once)

Comment: I understand you can get the values using the service, I was suggesting passing it from the parent component, so you can use the ngOnChanges life cycle method in the detail component, instead of the ngOnInit.

ngOnChanges will trigger everytime a data-bound property changes, so it will run every time the passed information changes

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Comment: thank you Facundo Gallardo.
I had used "(selectionChange)" from parent component and this method, i read the value of search Component using services.
than bind that value to detail component and read same value ngOnchange method in detail component. 
Sorry i did not have enough reputation, to post my answer.

Comment: Still if someone have solution about conditionally loading each component would be a clean approach. (If you have similar post) please advise.

Comment: I have resolve this using by creating Subject observables.

Comment: See youtube video for how to do communication between component to give some idea. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkH4rgP4Un8